# Matlab: Large Data Mapping char to Int

Tags: matlab, join, mapping, matlab-table

I have a matlab table with the following columns. Lets call this the 'reference table':
[Security(char),RegionId(int either 1,2,3) ]
This table is approximately 49,000 in height

I have other tables that contain Security(char) and a random data point as a column. Lets call these tables 'data tables'. 
The aggregate size of these data tables is 45Gigs. Each of these tables is >100million rows.
I need to use the reference table to map regionId and do the following:

[Security(char),RandomDataPoint(float)] > [Security(char),RegionId(int either 1,2,3),RandomDataPoint(float)]

Normally for this operation I would use a table join. However, I'm having real issues with this implementation because of the massive size of these tables. My primary problem is running out of memory.

One option is to break down the tables into sections and joining. However, I suspect this would very costly in terms of time considering 45Gigs of aggregate data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should approach this problem. If it matters, I need to add the region column to my data tables so I can write data to text files and bulk load them into sql.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you want / need to use MATLAB for this kind of task? how about using a dedicated database server, maybe interfacing using JDBC from MATLAB?

Comment: The issue is i'm getting fed .mat files. The other thing I can think of is creating a temp sql table with the reference data and a temp sql table for the data tables -> join in sql -> and then insert them into the table I desire. However, I would like to find something a little more aesthetic.

Comment: You might be insterested in mapreduce : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/process-big-data-in-matlab-using-mapreduce.html . I have never used it but seems fit to your task

Comment: If you is able to come in contact with the guy writing the files he would probably be an asset here. Someone have at least manage to generate huge .mat files, so I guess the same someone have an idea of how to read the data.

Comment: Thanks, I have not heard of it before. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

I know its bad taste to answer your own questions, but here is what I ended up with.

After a lot of testing, this is what I found to be fastest. 
I completely did away with joining.

```
maskfor1 = ismember(data.Securities,reference.Securities(reference.RegionId==1))
```

Now i decreased the number of securities i have to check against for regionId == 2 using the maskfor1. I then recreated what maskfor2 should look like.

```
maskFor2 = zeros(height(data.Securities),1);

minitureMaskFor2 = ismemeber(data.Securities(~masfor1),reference.Securities(reference.RegionId==2))

maskFor2(~maskfor2) = minitureMaskFor2;
```

The remaining were regionId = 3. Now use the masks to create a regionId column for the table.

This process took about a 1 min 20 sec to run for 100 million rows.